# Jquery - if contains is not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a block of code to check a  tag. if it contain a string in there then alert TRUE, otherwise alert FALSE.

But I always get alert TRUE. even though its not TRUE???..heres my code below.
hopefully someone can help me find the solution to this.

```
<h1>Hmmm, Its not working??</h1>
```

Jquery code

```
if($("h1:contains('Help me please')")) {
alert('TRUE');
} else {
alert('FALSE');
}
```

[Link to my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBaoAnhLe/uDbFj/)

Comment: The code works, it just doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery selector used by you always return a jQuery wrapper object which will be always a truthy value.

Instead what you can do is to use .is() to test whether any of the elements passed satisfied the passed selector

```
if ($("h1").is(":contains('Help me please')")) {
    alert('TRUE');
} else {
    alert('FALSE');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hNuXH/)

Or you can check the length of the elements found by the jQuery object

```
if ($("h1:contains('Help me please')").length) {
    alert('TRUE');
} else {
    alert('FALSE');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CFE9P)

Comment: You should explain why too, or he'll never learn the right way

Comment: Thank you so much! :). @RUJordan Sorry, I'm new to Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

`$("h1:contains('Help me please')")` returns an object 
and if(object) evaluates to true

so you can do

```
if ($("h1:contains('Help me please')").length > 0)
```

or

```
if ($("h1").is(":contains('Help me please')"))
```

instead